# KendoUI Grid Server Dynamic Column binding in service callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to understand the working of KendoUI Grid. I have successfully returned paged data from the server and server side paging is also working.

But I am having problem with setting column details dynamically i.e. neither the titles show up nor the template, the column header shows the name of bound field. I think the problem is related to when columns are initialized because I get to know about the details of columns after call back from the service.

Here is how I am binding the grid:

```
$("#kGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                serverPaging: true,
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total"
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                transport: {
                    read: function(options) {
                        var searchParam = new Model.SearchParamsCM('QuoteDomainTasks', 'QuoteList', false, options.data.page, options.data.pageSize);

                        seHttpService.GetWithParms('/spa/api/genericrequest', searchParam)
                            .then(function (result) {
                                var data = oThis.createJSONFromResults(result.data, oThis);

                                options.success(data);
                            },
                            function(result) {
                                options.error(result);
                            });
                    }
                }
            },
            columns: oThis._gridColumns, 
            scrollable: false,
            pageable: { "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true },
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true
        });
```

Where oThis._gridColumns is populated inside oThis.createJSONFromResults. This code is in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data source is only for reading the content of the grid, not its configuration (which only needs to be created once, when setting up the grid). You need to separate these two concerns so that `oThis._gridColumns` has the column definition when you call `$("#kGrid").kendoGrid()`.

Dynamically changing the column definitions is not really supported by Kendo Grid, so if you need that, your options are:

- recreate the whole grid whenever the column definition has to change
- change things manually (e.g. if only titles change, you could do that by selecting and editing the elements with jQuery)
- try to mess with the internals, e.g. something like the following

(note this is largely untested and might break with new Kendo UI releases)

```
grid.options.columns = changedColumnDefinition;
grid.table.find(">thead").empty();
grid._columns(grid.options.columns);
grid._thead();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! yes I can separate these two concerns but I will have to make two calls for it which I dont want to do. I dont understnd that if columns are configured before data is bound then how come header titles are being set from dataSource in my case?
Option 1: you mean, bind, destroy, create? but aint the 2nd creation will have same problem?
Option 2: I have to change the header title, setup links and checkboxes etc.

Comment: @Haris what's the problem with making this a second call? I don't really understand why you need the column definition to change for each page. If it doesn't change after the first call, you could probably combine the first `read` with the column definition. Also: what do you mean by "setup links" and checkboxes - where are those?

Comment: @Haris "how come header titles are being set from dataSource" - if you mean that the grid is using the column names as titles, that is the default if `columns` isn't set